# Displaying images inside table using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am sending requests to an API using AJAX and retrieving a response with JSON containing image urls and various metadata with it.

I am trying to display these images in a html table but for some reason `localhost:8000` (I am testing this from localhost) is being appended in the beginning of every url inside the image tag.

This is the code for generating the html from the AJAX response:

```
success: function(response) {
            var trHTML = '';
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                var img1 = '<a href="' + item.url1 + '"><img src=">' + item.url1 + '"></a>';
                var img2 = '<a href="' + item.url2 + '"><img src=">' + item.url2 + '"></a>';

                trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.score + '</td><td>' + img1 + '</td><td>' + img2 + '</td></tr>';
            });
                // append results to table
                $('#resultsTable').append(trHTML);
          }
```

Only 404 - img not found icons are displayed since they are pointing to the following urls:

```
http://localhost:8000/%3Ehttps://url-of-my-image.jpg
```

However, the url inside the `href` command is working just fine and is pointing to the correct location: `https://url-of-my-image.jpg`

Could someone explain what is going on? One time, the problem is only with the url inside `<img src='url'>` tag.

Comment: Shouldn't '<img src=">' + item.url1' be <img src="' + item.url1 (no > after src=

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you have an extra unnecessary closing angle bracket, try:

```
success: function(response) {
        var trHTML = '';
        $.each(response, function (i, item) {
            var img1 = '<a href="' + item.url1 + '"><img src="' + item.url1 + '"/></a>';
            var img2 = '<a href="' + item.url2 + '"><img src="' + item.url2 + '"/></a>';

            trHTML += '<tr><td>' + item.score + '</td><td>' + img1 + '</td><td>' + img2 + '</td></tr>';
        });
            // append results to table
            $('#resultsTable').append(trHTML);
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Such a dumb mistake and cost me so much time :)

Comment: Easy to miss sometimes when one is tired and been staring at the same piece of code for too long! :)